HTML Newbie - <Rect> Suddenly Cut off
I'm trying to make a basic website and want to have a long line drawn on the top of the site. Tried using , but it keeps getting cut off after setting 'width' above 500. How do I fix this issue?
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charmset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Wirtualna wizytówka"> </meta>
        <meta name="keywords" content="radca prawny, prawo, radca, prawoznawca, pomoc prawna, prawnik"> </meta>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title >Prawny</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #ffffff;">
        <svg>
             <rect x="70" y="50" rx="5" ry="5" width="500" height="10" fill="black" />
          </svg>          
    </body>
</html>`

I have a reference to style.css that I will use later, but for now it remains blank

If you're making a website, and are still learning, do not use SVG. Make it a <hr> and style it with CSS.

give the  element a width e.g. width="100%". You may want to provide a height too.

Thank You very much for the answers. Will try both and update with the results

Update: Both things worked, and I ended up going with the 2nd option as I needed to have a split in the middle. Thank You very much for the help!

Your HTML is invalid. There is no closing </meta> tag. Remove those.

Use a viewBox for the svg element. Please try <svg viewBox="0 0 640 110">

When learning SVG apply a background; so you always see where your SVG is and what size it is: <svg style="background:pink"> Use a viewBox to size the SVG
